# How to capture a zero number without it getting lost?

Tags: c

I am learning C, using programming in C by Steve Kochan.

I am currently stuck on question 6 of, by one little part, I am supposed to let the user input a number and the program is going to converted to words, (932 = nine three two) etc.

I have the program up and running, and I ran into a little issue, the number 0, every time I input a number with a 0 whether is leading, middle or end, it always get lost.

My thinking on the program was reversing the number, and then reversing it again but this time displaying the words through a switch statement so they can be display in the correct order, but the 0 gets lost of course because I am using modulus operation.

Here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

        int main(void)
        {
            int userNumber, tempNumber, rightDigit, newNumber = 0;

            printf("Please enter any nonnegative 3 digit number: ");
            scanf_s("%i", &userNumber);                 // ask for users input

            if (userNumber < 0 || userNumber > 999)
            {
                printf("Number is out of the range!\n");                
            }                                                   // checks for numbers outside of rane   

            do
            {                                                           // loop to reverse the number, ex 932 to 239
                rightDigit = userNumber % 10;
                tempNumber = rightDigit;

                if (userNumber > 99 && userNumber < 1000)
                {
                    tempNumber *= 100;
                    newNumber += tempNumber;
                }
                else if (userNumber > 9 && userNumber < 100)
                {
                    tempNumber *= 10;
                    newNumber += tempNumber;
                }
                else if (userNumber >= 0 && userNumber < 10)
                {
                    newNumber += tempNumber;
                }

                userNumber /= 10;

            } while (userNumber != 0);

            do
            {                                               // loop to extrac the last digit and assigned the word in english for that number
                rightDigit = newNumber % 10;

                switch (rightDigit)
                {
                    case 1: 
                        printf("One ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        printf("Two ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        printf("Three ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        printf("Four ");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        printf("Five ");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        printf("Six ");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        printf("Seven ");
                        break;
                    case 8: 
                        printf("Eight ");
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        printf("Nine ");
                        break;

                            case 0:

                        printf("Zero");

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                newNumber /= 10;

            } while (newNumber != 0);

            printf("\n");

            return 0;
        }
```

I am looking to guidance on how I can achieve being able to print out zero.

Comment: Why don't you have a case for zero?

Comment: Thanks Matt, I took it out on accident when I was messing with the code to try and get the zero in there, it is back in, unfortunately it doesn't do anything because the 0 is getting lost in the first loop, I need to be able to bring it to the second.

Comment: While reversing the number, the code should be counting the number of digits in the number. The loop that prints the digits should print exactly that number of digits. For example, if the number is 700, reversing the digits results in `newnumber` equal to 7 with a count of 3. In the second loop, you print 3 digits, even though `newnumber` is zero after printing the 7.

Comment: Why don't you just convert the number to text with `sprintf` and then process the digits left to right as characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Look-up table: dig[n] is the word
 * representing digit n, for 0 <= n <= 9.
 */
char *digstr[] = {
  "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
  "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"
};

int main(void)
{
  int num;
  char *words[30];
  int i = 0;

  /* Try to scan an int from standard
   * input. The return value of scanf is
   * 1 if a conversion was successfully made.
   * This doesn't handle integer overflow.
   * Let's just bail with a failed termination
   * status if the scan is not successful, or
   * the resulting number is negative.
   */
  if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num < 0)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  /* Push the digit words into the words[]
   * stack in right to left order.
   * E.g. if the number is 23, then
   * words[0] is "three", words[1] is "two".
   */
  while (num > 0) {
    words[i++] = digstr[num % 10];
    num /= 10;
  }

  /* If we didn't push anything into the word
   * stack, the number must be zero. So let's push
   * in a zero.
   */
  if (i == 0)
    words[i++] = digstr[0];

  /* Now pop the words from the stack in reverse
   * order: word[0] is printed last.
   * Print a space after every word other than
   * the last one
   */
  while (--i >= 0)
    printf("%s%s", words[i], (i > 0) ? " " : "");

  /* Terminate the line of output and exit
   * successfully.
   */
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Another solution is to let the C library's I/O routine do the job of converting the number to decimal digits. We capture that into a  string using `sprintf` and then loop over the digits left to right. A digit character `'0'` through `'9'` can be converted to the integer value  0 to 9 by subtracting the character `'0'`. In other words `'9' - '0' == 9` and `'7' - '0' == 7` and so on. Using the integer value, we look up the word in the `digstr` look-up table as before.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Look-up table: dig[n] is the word
 * representing digit n, for 0 <= n <= 9.
 */
char *digstr[] = {
  "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
  "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"
};

int main(void)
{
  int num;
  char num_text[32];
  int i;

  /* Try to scan an int from standard
   * input. The return value of scanf is
   * 1 if a conversion was successfully made.
   * This doesn't handle integer overflow.
   * Let's just bail with a failed termination
   * status if the scan is not successful, or
   * the resulting number is negative.
   */
  if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num < 0)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  /* Convert the number to a character
   * string.
   */
  sprintf(num_text, "%d", num);

  /* Process the digits to words. If num_text[i]
   * is zero, we have hit the null terminating
   * byte of the string. We write a space after
   * each word if there is a next digit in the
   * string; num_text[i + 1] is the null byte
   * when num_text[i] is the last digit.
   */
  for (i = 0; num_text[i]; i++)
    printf("%s%s", digstr[num_text[i] - '0'], num_text[i + 1] ? " " : "");

  /* Terminate the line of output and exit
   * successfully.
   */
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```